# When to add an category to a managed object and when to use transient attributes?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, ios5, nsmanagedobject

I would like to add a custom calculation method to a managed object (which calculates some date based on other properties of this object).

I am not sure if it is better to code this as an transient attribute or to add a property in an category to this managed object.

What do you think?

This is my current code (category):

.h:

```
@interface IBFinPeriod (DateCalculations)
@property (readonly) NSDate* periodBeginDate;
@end
```

.m:

```
#import "IBFinPeriod+DateCalculations.h"

@implementation IBFinPeriod (DateCalculations)

- (NSDate*)periodBeginDate
{
    NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    if ([self.incPeriodTypeCode isEqualToString:@"M"]) {
        offsetComponents.month = - [self.incPeriodLength intValue];
    } else if ([self.incPeriodTypeCode isEqualToString:@"W"]) {
        offsetComponents.week = - [self.incPeriodLength intValue];
    }
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDate *beginDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:self.EndDate options:0];
    return beginDate;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution seems fine. If you used a transient property, you'd still need the code to calculate its value, so you'd need a category anyway.

I guess having a transient property would make more sense if you access its value very often, in which case you'd want to cache its value. If you're going to access the value only a few times, there's no need for that.

Comment: +1 to the suggestion that go for transient _only_ if you want caching. But know that once the value is cached, you must change it explicitly or send -refreshObject:mergeChanges: to calculate it again. So you'd have to go for key-value-observing and set the transient value instead of having the property itself calculated on-the-fly.

Answer (score 1):

The provided readonly property on a category is simple -- by a long shot. And doesnt dirty up that object model.

But the transient property method is sexy for the user, since the derived property is updated automagically.
ANd it goes a little Something like this...

```
@implementation IBFinPeriod (IBFinPeriod_Observations)


- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

    if ([@"incPeriodTypeCode" isEqualToString: keyPath]  ) {
        [self updatePeriodBeginDate];
    }
    else {
        [super observeValueForKeyPath: keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
    }
}


- (void)updatePeriodBeginDate
{
    NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    if ([self.incPeriodTypeCode isEqualToString:@"M"]) {
        offsetComponents.month = - [self.incPeriodLength intValue];
    } else if ([self.incPeriodTypeCode isEqualToString:@"W"]) {
        offsetComponents.week = - [self.incPeriodLength intValue];
    }
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDate *beginDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:self.EndDate options:0];

    // NOW SET THE TRANSIENT PROPERTY HERE
    [self setPeriodBeginDate: beginDate];
//        return beginDate; // NOt returning anymore
}


@end
```